# javascript : make a new safe class constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, node.js

sometimes we loss the new keyword when define new object,

```
obj = new Clazz(); //correct
obj = Clazz(); //wrong, but no syntax error, hard to debug.
```

I want to write a function to help me create Class and make it new safe.

```
var Class = function(){
   var constructor = arguments[0];
   var superClasses = arguments[1..n];
   function clazz(){
     if(! this instanceof clazz){
         return new clazz()//pass clazz arguments,not Class arguments
     }
     constructor();//pass clazz arguments
   }

   //clazz inherit from superClasses 

   return clazz;
}

var MyClazz = Class(function(name){
    this.name = name
}, SuperClazz1, SuperClass2 )

MyClazz.extend({
    show: function(){console.log(this.name)}
})

obj1 = new MyClazz("name1"); 
obj2 = MyClazz("name2");
// obj1 should same as obj2
```

Is it possible, any exists module?

Answer (score 3):

> sometimes we loss the new keyword...

All about coding discipline and testing... anyways, moving on to your question.

To find out whether your function was called as a constructor use `instanceof`:

```
function Foo() {
    console.log(this instanceof Foo);
}

Foo();  // false
new Foo(); // true
```

When calling a function as a constructor `this` refers to the newly created object, otherwise `this` refers to the object the function was called on, in case it wasn't called on anything `this` will refer to the global object.

**Update**

Passing variable arguments to a constructor is not possible. `new clas.call(....)` will yield an error that `call` is not an constructor.

You can do two things:

1. Instead of returning the `Class` function itself from your class factory method, return a function that creates a new instance, sets up all the needed stuff and then returns that instance (this will make inheritance waaaay more complicated)
2. Just use the `new` keyword.

I've written my own [Class thingy](https://github.com/BonsaiDen/neko.js), and I've tried to support both `new` and `()` syntax for creating instances. The whole inheritance stuff etc. is complicated enough, making it even more magic just to save **4** more characters... not worth the effort. Use `new` and write tests.

**Another Update**

OK I couldn't resist to hack around more and I made it work:

```
function is(type, obj) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(obj).slice(8, -1) === type;
}

function clas(args) {
    if (is('Object', this)) {
        ctor.apply(this, is('Arguments', args) ? args : arguments);

    } else {
        return new clas(arguments);
    }
}
```

This will do the magic, at least in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late submission on this answer but I believe it directly answers your question. My solution is to check the type of the constructed object and act accordingly.

You can see my solution here:
http://mikepackdev.com/blog_posts/9-new-scope-safe-constructors-in-oo-javascript

I hope this helps!

Comment: Would love to see your answer - can you inline the solution, cos yr blog is down :/